# "MKL ERROR: Parameter 12..." for large matrices with scipy.linalg.eigvalsh in Anaconda 2019.10-py37 (updated)

Tags: python, python-3.x, scipy, anaconda, intel-mkl

First of all, note that the problem seems to exist for a long time now (e.g. [GitHub Scipy Issue 8205](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/issues/8205)). 
It happens that I get an MKL error (see below) when trying to get the eigenvalues of complex matrices with size 2000x2000 or larger using `eigvalsh`.
Apparently, the problem should have been fixed on the MKL side with release 2019.0 as far as I understand, so I upgraded Anaconda to 2018.12-py37 since Scipy is linked against MKL 2019.1 in this version. Unfortunately, this does not work for me and I still get the error. Did I miss something or is there a fix in sight for this? There seems to be no MKL conda-forge version of Scipy so it might be the most recent version available (in Anaconda with MKL).

Anaconda Release 2018.12-py37

an extract from `conda list`:

```
# Name                    Version                   Build  Channel
blas                      1.0                         mkl
mkl                       2019.1                      144
numpy                     1.15.4           py37h7e9f1db_0
numpy-base                1.15.4           py37hde5b4d6_0
scipy                     1.1.0            py37h7c811a0_2
```

I have already built a virtual conda environment with only the necessary modules. It raises the same errors.

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.linalg import eigvalsh
mat = np.random.rand(2000,2000) + 1j * np.random.rand(2000,2000)
mat += mat.conjugate().T
eigvalsh(mat)
```

I get the following error:

```
Intel MKL ERROR: Parameter 12 was incorrect on entry to ZHBRDB.
```

It just raises the error and returns an array with only zeros, except for the last entry.

Edit:

Now with Anaconda Release 2019.10-py37, i invested some more time and was able to trace the problem down to the point where LAPACK functions are wrapped:

`eigvalsh` calls `eigh` with `eigvals_only=True`.
By investigating the `eigh` routine, I found out that the main difference is in setting the flag `jobz` for the LAPACK function to 'N' (only eigenvalues) instead of 'V' (eigenvalues and eigenvectors). By reconstructing the code I was able to test the wrapped `heevr` routine for different cases - application to complex64 and complex 128 hermitian matrices give the error as explained above, application to float32 and float64 symmetric matrices give no error and reasonable results for at least up to 20kx20k randomly generated matrices.

A new minimal example:

```py
    from numpy.random import rand
    from scipy.linalg.lapack import get_lapack_funcs
    mat = rand(2000,2000) + 1j * rand(2000,2000)
    mat += mat.conjugate().T
    (heevr,) = get_lapack_funcs(('heevr',), (mat,))
    (syevr,) = get_lapack_funcs(('syevr',), (mat.real,))
    w, v, info = heevr(mat, jobz='N') # produces error as described
    #w, v, info = heevr(mat, jobz='V') # no error
    #w, v, info = syevr(mat.real, jobz='N') # no error
    #w, v, info = syevr(mat.real, jobz='V') # no error
    print(w, v, info)
```

The variable `info` is 0 in every case.

Comment: Still present in Anaconda Release 2019.10-py37

Comment: Checked the MKL library with a piece of Fortran code, works great. So I guess the problem is in the wrapper (maybe calculating the work?)

Comment: Appears to be fixed by
https://github.com/scipy/scipy/pull/11304